# Ubuntu LTS bootable disk drive issue

Tags: boot, live-usb, downloads, nouveau

I am trying to create a bootable disk drive so that I can boot Ubuntu from the drive. I used Rufus to install the ISO to the drive. The external drive I am using is a crucial x8.

I get to the point where I choose try or install Ubuntu and then I get what is shown in the attached picture. I am attempting to use Ubuntu 22.04.3 and have tried re-downloading and rewriting the drive. This is the error I get:

[image: Screenshot]

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.